# nullpointer on android intent

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

Somehow I am getting an nullpointer when trying to execute my intent using startActivity. The only problem is that I am having the same statement in a different class. And that one is executed correctly without any problem. This is the piece of code which is causing the error:

```
public class GetPreferences extends Activity {

String result, Gebruikersnaam, Wachtwoord, LicentieCode, DeviceId, GebGUID;
FeatureSettings settings;
StringEntity seParams;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.frmlogin);
    Intent startApp = new Intent(this, actMain.class);
    startApp.putExtra("afterLogin", 1);
    startActivity(startApp);
}
```

this is the error log:

```
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.koeriers.tools/com.koeriers.erasmus.actMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2172)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at com.koeriers.erasmus.actMain.<init>(actMain.java:76)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2163)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    ... 11 more
```

and here is the defintion of the class in my manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.koeriers.erasmus.actMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

I know that my actMain class isn't even being loaded, because I've added a Log.e statement. And that isn't even being executed. So it must be the startActivity part, but I just can't see what is going wrong. So I hope you guys can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

@edit

here is my actMain.class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TLogFile.appendLog("i", "ACTMAIN", "OnCreate Started", true);

    SetDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

    settings = new FeatureSettings(getApplicationContext());
    TTools.DisableTitleBar(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.frmmain);
    TLogFile.appendLog("i", "actMain", "onCreate");

    pbMain = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbMain);

    HeaderIcon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.HeaderIcon);
    HeaderIcon.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(configfeatures.HeaderIconColor));

    lblHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblHeader);
    lblHeader.setText("Order overzicht");
    lblHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(configfeatures.HeaderStateColor));

    linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llMain);
    linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(configfeatures.BackgroundColor));

    if (configfeatures.Foto) {
        btnPicture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPicture);
        btnPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnPicture.setOnClickListener(this);
    } else {
        btnPicture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPicture);
        btnPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    btnLogout = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnTSync = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnTSync);
    btnTSync.setOnClickListener(this);

    Boolean bJustLoggedIn = false;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        bJustLoggedIn = extras.getInt("afterLogin") == 1;
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }

    if (bJustLoggedIn) {
        StartSyncing();
    }

    if (configfeatures.LocatieGegevens){
        StartLocationService();
    }

    // kijken of er een register actie is geweest
    if ((this.getIntent().getExtras() != null)
            && (this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("pushType") != null)
            && (this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("pushType").contains("1"))) {
        TPushHandler pushHandler = new TPushHandler();
        pushHandler.CheckPushMessages(this.getIntent(), this);
    }

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    if(configfeatures.LocatieGegevens){
        StartLocationThread();
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the actMain class ? 
Ps : The first letter of a class should be a capital.

Comment: whats the code for actMain class ?

Comment: No that is only recommended not required, but sure I'll post it

Comment: my guess is that the null pointer exception is occurring when you are trying to get extras which are passed from GetPreferences activity

Comment: no even when I remove the extras and check in the actMain.class whether the extras exists or not (to avoid a nullpointer). I am getting a nullpointer when executing the startActivity

Comment: did you change the class name because class name first letter should be capital letter.

Comment: You could go into debug mode and put a breakpoint at start of onCreate() of actMain. Advance step by step and you will know the exact line where your exception come from.

Comment: no I haven't changed it, but like I said it is discouraged to use a lowercase letter. So not required. But I will try to change it to a capital letter to see if it solves the error

Comment: still getting the nullpointer exception

Comment: plz point out where is line 76 code

Comment: As ridcully has already pointed out you cannot call getApplicationContext before onCreate is called. You need to initialize the field on line 76 in OnCreate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `getApplicationContext` in the initialization of `actMain`. (in the constructor or in a member declaration).

You cannot do that. The **context** in not initialized until `onCreate` is called. Move the call to `getApplicationContext` to `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved it. Should have looked a little bit further then the startActivity...

Answer (score 2):

According to the StackTrace, there's a NPE at line 76 of your actMain class. The `<init>` hints that the exception raises when the object is created, so *before* calling your `onCreate()` method. Probably in a constructor or initialising a global variable.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
06-14 09:51:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(28368):    at com.koeriers.erasmus.actMain.<init>(actMain.java:76)
```